# MySQL Cursor Doesn't Fetch Data

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, cursor

I used the following sample from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/ to concat a query result and return it as a string in a mysql database.

When I execute the query outside the procedure it returns the email result list. But when I execute the same query using the cursor in the procedure or function, the result is empty.

What is the difference?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_email_list (INOUT email_list varchar(4000))
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_email varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

    -- declare cursor for employee email
    DEClARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT email FROM employees;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN email_cursor;

    get_email: LOOP

        FETCH email_cursor INTO v_email;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_email;
        END IF;

        -- build email list
        SET email_list = CONCAT(v_email,";",email_list);

    END LOOP get_email;

    CLOSE email_cursor;

END
```

Comment: Did you ever get resolution on this? I have the identical code and problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using one query :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ';') AS email_list FROM employees;
```